# JavaFX multiple stages

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to using Java FX and was wondering if anyone could provide some answers for me on creating multiple independent stages. I'm also using Scene Builder for ActionEvents.

An example of multiple stages could be something like this:
Login page -> main stage -> other sub stages.
The way I understand is that you need a FXML loader on each controller to bring up each stage. So on my Main java class, under START method, I'll bring up a Login stage. And on my Login Controller, I'll have a method to bring up a Main Stage (i.e. once the Login button is pressed), and finally/similarly, I'll have a method under my Main Controller to bring up other sub stages, once a button to that sub stage is pressed from the Main Stage.
Is this the right way of opening new stages? Or do I have to have all the methods in one main class to open all the stages?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is, perhaps, a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Consider whether, for your primary navigation model, a preferred system is to change the content within the current scene rather than creating a new stage.  The preferred answer may be dependent on your application and the current function it is performing.  Often, a good choice for many applications and functions is having a single stage, with content changing within the scene, and the occasional dialog for things such as opening files or confirming discarding unsaved work.

Answer (score 1):

no you don't need to have to have all the methods in one main class to open all the stages. you can create your new stages in other controller when they need to be built. for example in your login page, in the controller when a button is clicked And you want to go to main stage,  code for the event be like:

```
            FXMLLoader main = new FXMLLoader();
            main.setLocation(getClass().getResource("adress"));
            Parent mainParent = main.load();
            Scene mainScene = new Scene(mainParent);

            Scene currentScene = anItemOfProgram.getScene();
            Stage stage = (Stage) currentScene.getWindow();

            stage.setScene(mainScene);
```

and this is right way to create multiple stages

Comment: That doesn't actually create multiple stages. It replaces the scene in the current stage (which may be suitable for the OP's needs). And another option is to replace the root node of the current scene (which is often better than replacing the scene).